# NoMachine v5.0.47 Connection Drops without Error

Tags: linux, nomachine

Has anyone experienced this behavior? On average, every hour or so, the connection just dies without any warning or errors and goes to the Recent Connections home page. I just click connect again, and I'm connected once again and the after another hour or so it will die again.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is look in logs for potential errors. This could be happening for any reason, not even related to NoMachine. The alternative is to contact them for help. Forums is a good start.